# How to get multiple 32bit values with byte array?

Tags: python, arrays, byte, slice

I need to extract some number values out of a binary data stream. 
the code below is working for me, but for sure there is a more suitable way to do this in python. Especially I was struggling a lot to find a better way to iterate over the array and get 4 byte as byte arrays from the buffer.

some hint for me?

```
outfile = io.BytesIO()
outfile.writelines(some binary data stream)
buf = outfile.getvalue()

blen = int(len(buf) / 4 );

for i in range(blen):
   a = bytearray([0,0,0,0])

   a[0] = buf[i*4]
   a[1] = buf[i*4+1]
   a[2] = buf[i*4+2]
   a[3] = buf[i*4+3]
   data = struct.unpack('<l', a)[0]
   do something with data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question and accompanying pseudo-code are somewhat hazy in my opinion, but here's something that uses slices of `buf` to obtain the each group of 4 bytes needed—so if nothing else it's at least a bit more succinct (assuming I've correctly interpreted what you're asking):

```
import io
import struct

outfile = io.BytesIO()
outfile.writelines([b'\x00\x01\x02\x03',
                    b'\x04\x05\x06\x07'])
buf = outfile.getvalue()

for i in range(0, len(buf), 4):
   data = struct.unpack('<l', buf[i:i+4])[0]
   print(hex(data))
```

Output:

```
0x3020100
0x7060504
```